# RHEL6 SRPMs Are Not Found by "yumdownloader"

Tags: redhat, yum, rpm

I am trying to download SRPMs from redhat from what of their servers.  I went through step one of initializing the repository...

```
# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/rhel-source.repo 
[rhel-source]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch - Source
baseurl=ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/$releasever/en/os/SRPMS/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
```

Then I did a yum update, and everything to make sure my repo database was up to date.  When I go to download the source, however...

```
# yumdownloader --source gcc
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
No source RPM found for gcc-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64
No source RPM found for gcc-4.4.5-6.el6.x86_64
Nothing to download
```

I went through the same steps on CentOS 5 and it works.  (Though, I'm using the CentOS repository, not RHEL's...  Still, I'm puzzled.  I even FTP'ed their server manually and looked

```
ftp> ls gcc*
227 Entering Passive Mode (209,132,183,61,19,97).
150 Here comes the directory listing.
-rw-r--r--    4 ftp      ftp      52214716 Aug 17  2010 gcc-4.4.4-13.el6.src.rpm
-rw-r--r--    5 ftp      ftp      52113813 Apr 21 20:28 gcc-4.4.5-6.el6.src.rpm
226 Directory send OK.
ftp>
```

Those look like SRPMs to me...  what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `$releasever` evaluate to? Also, that repo should be disabled by default; `yumdownloader` will enable it as appropriate.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams It resolves to "6Server", making the full path   `ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in yum-utils, nothing that you're doing wrong.

I did a little crude "print" debugging between my RHEL 6 server, and My Fedora 14 workstation.  Right after line 47 & 48 in /usr/bin/yumdownloader:

```
(n,v,r,e,a) = rpmUtils.miscutils.splitFilename(pkg.sourcerpm)
src = self.pkgSack.searchNevra(name=n, ver=v, rel=r, arch='src')
```

I added a couple of debugging statements and found the following:

From my RHEL 6 server (indented areas following "Debug:" being the areas of interest):

```
# yumdownloader --source gcc
Loaded plugins: presto, rhnplugin
Enabling epel-source repository
Debug: 
    pkg.sourcerpm = gcc-4.4.4-13.el6.src.rpm
    n = gcc
    v = 4.4.4
    r = 13.el6
    src = []
No source RPM found for gcc-4.4.4-13.el6.x86_64
Debug: 
    pkg.sourcerpm = gcc-4.4.5-6.el6.src.rpm
    n = gcc
    v = 4.4.5
    r = 6.el6
    src = []
No source RPM found for gcc-4.4.5-6.el6.x86_64
Nothing to download
```

From my Fedora 14 workstation:

```
# yumdownloader --source gcc
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
Enabling updates-source repository
Enabling rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-source repository
Enabling rpmfusion-nonfree-source repository
Enabling rpmfusion-free-updates-source repository
Enabling fedora-source repository
Enabling rpmfusion-free-source repository
Debug: 
    pkg.sourcerpm = gcc-4.5.1-4.fc14.src.rpm
    n = gcc
    v = 4.5.1
    r = 4.fc14
    src = [<YumAvailablePackageSqlite : gcc-4.5.1-4.fc14.src (0xe5e150)>]
gcc-4.5.1-4.fc14.src.rpm                                 |  52 MB     00:38
```

So we know what src "should" be, based off of Fedora 14.  /usr/bin/yumdownloader is identical between RHEL6, and Fedora 14 (md5sums match).  However the yum-utils libraries that yumdownloader is leveraging are different between RHEL6 and Fedora 14, and that is likely the culprit.

I'd file a [bug](http://bugzilla.redhat.com/) with Redhat against the yum-utils package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried to go and verify it by opening a ticket with RedHat.  Their site let me actually open a ticket, but since I'm only in trial version, they didn't have the time for me...  Understandable.

Accepted anyway, cause your logs you posted have compelling evidence of what's going on; or at least that I'm not really doing anything wrong, which was the question ;)